# Python: Iterate Over Dictionary that Contains Lists and Store the Keys and Values in a String

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterator

```
params={
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': ['value_a','value_b']
}
```

This is what I'm starting with but it can't handle the list.

```
str_params = ''
for key, value in params.items():
    print (key,value)
    str_params += '&' + key + '=' + value
```

I'm trying to yield this string.

```
str_params = '&key1=value1&key2=value_a&key2=value_b'
```

Comment: What do you expect the `str_params` to looks like after the loop?

Comment: str_params = 'key1=value1&key2=value_a&key2=value_b'

Comment: So you wnat url-encode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating a dictionary yields keys only. If you want key, value pairs to be yielded, use `items()` method (`iteritems` in Python 2.x).

Use [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) ([`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) in Python 2.x):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode([
...     (key, x) for key, xs in params.items()
...     for x in ([xs] if isinstance(xs, str) else xs)
... ])
'key2=value_a&key2=value_b&key1=value1'
```

You can use manual string opeator, but it require extra care for special characters that should be `%xx`-encoded.

Comment: I modified my question a bit. I failed to originally include what I wanted the string to look like. sorry

Comment: @goopcat, I also modified answer accordingly. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about urllib and it's exactly what I am doing. It's like you read my mind, Haha.

Comment: @goopcat, If you gave the expected output, it would be a lot easier to read your mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `items()` to access the key and value in dictionary :

```
>>> for i,j in params.items():
...  str_params+= '&' +i+'='+str(j)
```

Comment: surly yes ! ;) its that !

Comment: `str(j)` will not give what OP want for lists.

Comment: i know that dear @falsetru  Fortunately you do it ! and take my vote !